# Split configuration in more files in Silex

Tags: php, silex

I am using Silex PHP framework.

I have two files, the first is *app.php*:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

$app = new Silex\Application();

 $app['debug'] = true;
 $app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
'db.options' => array(
    'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'dbname'    => 'testapp',
    'user'      => 'root',
    'password'  => 'turoke55u',
    ),
));
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
    }
});
$app->mount('/', include 'login.php');
$app->run();
```

And the second is *login.php*:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$login = $app['controllers_factory'];
$login->post('/apiv1/user/login', function (Request $request) use ($login) {
    $userinfo = array(
        'email'  => $request->request->get('email'),
        'mode'  => $request->request->get('mode'),
        'password'  => $request->request->get('password'),
    );
    $passwordcoding = sha1($userinfo['email']."66643asd");
    $emailverification = "SELECT email,password FROM user WHERE email='".$userinfo['email']."'";
    $selectemail = $login['db']->$fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user');
    var_dump($emailverification);
});
return $login;
```

When I run the select on db I get this error:

> Cannot use object of type Silex\ControllerCollection as array in /mnt/hgfs/Share_Folder/frontend/src/login.php on line 13

Does someone know a solution for that issue?

I have a second question, why if I change in *app.php* this:

```
$app->mount('/', include 'login.php');
```

To this:

```
$app->mount('/apiv1/user/login', include 'login.php');
```

And in *login.php*:

```
$login->post('/',
```

Like in the Silex documentation, the framework doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a silly error in your function signature:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$login = $app['controllers_factory'];

$login->post('/apiv1/user/login', function (Request $request) use ($login) {
//                                                                ^^^^^^^^
// this should be $app, not $login as this function is using the container
    $userinfo = array(
        'email'  => $request->request->get('email'),
        'mode'  => $request->request->get('mode'),
        'password'  => $request->request->get('password'),
    );
    $passwordcoding = sha1($userinfo['email']."66643asd");
    $emailverification = "SELECT email,password FROM user WHERE email='".$userinfo['email']."'";

    // here you're using the $login as the container and it's a controller collection, so in the signature use the container not the $login
    //             vvvvvvvvvvvv
    $selectemail = $login['db']->$fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user');

    var_dump($emailverification);
});
return $login;
```

As for the second doubt you should elaborate more on "the framework doesn't work", explain the symptoms and the output (if error which error?)